# How do you document instance variables so PyDev can display the doc?

Tags: pydev

Recently installed Eclipse/PyDev to help with development of a Python project that has grown to big to be developed in a single file.  I've been using its abilities to display docstrings when hovering and want to extend this to docstrings for instance variables like below.  However, I can't get it to work and can't seem to find anything saying whether it should work or not.  Is it possible?

```
class Foo(object):
    """ Shows up as docstring """
    def __init__(self):
       """ Does not show up when hovering over x """
       self.x = None
       """ Also doesn't show up when hovering over x """
```

(The PyDev contact page says to ask general questions on SO and tag with pydev so that's what I'm doing.)

Comment: There's currently no such feature in PyDev. Please open a feature request for it.

Comment: Done.  See 3526583 on the Sourceforge feature tracker.